# Send WhatsApp message using a form on a WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, whatsapp

I want to make a button that when clicked, customers directly message me via WhatsApp. I'm using WordPress. For anti-spam reasons I want to store the link in my `function.php` not directly in my HTML.

I'm now using `wp-redirect` but that takes them off my site. I don't want that. So how do I do this? I'm fairy new to coding.

function.php

```
 // Check if the button has been clicked
if ( isset( $_POST['whatsApp_btn'] ) ) {
    // Call your function here
    my_WhatsApp();
}

// Define your function
function my_WhatsApp() {
    // Redirect to a URL

  wp_redirect( 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=MyPhoneNumber' );
 
    exit;
}
```

index.php

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="whatsApp_btn" target="_blank" class="whatsapp" alt="Link to WhatsApp Chat" :focus>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
        <i> whatsApp Ons</i></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcode and call it in the `index.php`.

First, you create the shortcode in your `function.php`:

```
<?php
function custom_whatsapp_buttom() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
      <a class="whatsapp" alt="Link to WhatsApp Chat" target="__blank"
        href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=MyPhoneNumber&text=Text example">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
          <i>whatsApp Ons</i>
      </a>
    <?php
    ob_end_flush();
}

add_shortcode('whatsapp-btn-shortcode', 'custom_whatsapp_buttom');
```

- I'm using `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` to pass the html markup.
- I'm using an `<a>` tag instead of a `<buttom>`.
- I also added a text sample to the URL.

---

You can add the shortcode to your `index.php` file like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[whatsapp-btn-shortcode]'); ?>
```

You can change the name of the shortcode `whatsapp-btn-shortcode` if you want. Hope it helps you.